# getting an error in my palindrome java program

Tags: java

I have created a palindorme java program which is getting an error.the error is saying int cannot be converted to boolean.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
public class palindrome
{
    public static void main()
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int l,i;
        String s,s1;
        System.out.println("Enter your string");
        s = sc.nextLine();
        l = s.length();
        for(i=0;l-i-1;i++)
        {
            s1 = s + s.charAt(i);
        }
        if(s1==s) 
            System.out.println("This is Palindrome");
         else
         System.out.println("This is not a Palindrome");
        }
    }
```

Comment: your condition in the for loop seems wrong. At least my IDE shows an error there

Comment: What are you expecting `l-i-1` to mean in your loop condition?

Comment: Also you are comparing strings in a wrong way (in this case) - use `equals`

Answer (score 1):

For loop condition seems wrong.

```
for(initial counter; condition to terminate; increase counter) {}
for(i=0; i<l; i++) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Along with the answer above you can try a different approach. You don't need to go all the string length to check a palindrome. A palindrome can be checked iterating half of the array length like this -

```
public void checkPalindrome(String strToCheck){
      char[] arr = strToCheck.toCharArray();
      int size = arr.length;
      char [] original = Arrays.copyOf(arr,arr.length);

      for (int i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) {
         char temp = arr[i];
         arr[i] = arr[size-i-1];
         arr[size-i-1] = temp;
      }

      if(Arrays.equals(arr, original)) {
         System.out.println("Palindrome");
      } else {
         System.out.println("Not a palindrome");
      }
}
```

**What are done here:**

- reversing the string first iterating the halfway
- comparing the reversed string with the original using `Arrays.equals()` method.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few things off here, first here is the fixed code:

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int l,i;
    String s = "",s1 = "";
    System.out.println("Enter your string");
    s = sc.nextLine();
    l = s.length();
    for(i = l - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        s1 = s1 + s.charAt(i);
    }
    if(s1.equals(s)) 
        System.out.println("This is Palindrome");
    else
        System.out.println("This is not a Palindrome");
}
```

The first thing to fix was your `for` loop, as you saw you were getting an error.  This was fixed by setting the initial `i` to the length minus 1, changing the loop condition to `i >= 0`, and using `i--` to subtract 1 from `i` each loop.

These changes to the loop were made so that the character starting from the last position in the `String` is the first one being return by `s.charAt(i)` so you can reverse the `String`.  I think you were attempting to do something along these lines to add the characters starting from the end to a `String`.

I also changed `s1 = s + s.charAt(i)` to `s1 = s1 + s.charAt()` so the correct `String` is being appended.  (This should probably be `StringBuilder` however).

`s` and `s1` now have the initial condition of `""` instead of nothing.

And finally you cannot compare `String` equality with `==`, it must be `s1.equals(s)`.

**Test Run:**

> Enter your string
>
> racecar
>
> This is Palindrome